# Removing SOAP XML headers in React Native

Tags: json, react-native, soap, libxml-js

I'm using node [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js) package for converting my response soap xml data to json. As json object I get this output.

```
{
  "SOAP-ENV:Envelope" : {
     "SOAP-ENV:Body": {
       "ns:anotherTitle": ...
    }
  }
}
```

and so on. What I want to do is remove this SOAP-ENV:, ns: for better json structure. How do I achieve this?

Thanks a lot.